# Cannot connect to mongodb on docker

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I am writing to you to ask for help as I have been struggling all day to connect an application running on docker to mongodb, which is also on docker.
Here's how the not-so-developed code (just for testing) for connecting to mongodb looks:

```
client = MongoClient(f"mongodb://{MONGODB_URL}", ssl=False)


async def save_to_mongodb(data):
    try:
        db = client["my_db"]
        collection = db["my_db_collection"]
        collection.insert_one(data)
        print("Successfully connected to MongoDB and inserted a document.")
    except ServerSelectionTimeoutError:
        print("Failed to connect to MongoDB")
```

I am takimg MONGO_URL from .env which is in general:

```
MONGODB_USERNAME=user
MONGODB_PASSWORD=userPass
MONGODB_HOST=mongodb
MONGODB_PORT=27018
MONGODB_AUTH_SOURCE=admin
MONGODB_URL=${MONGODB_USERNAME}:${MONGODB_PASSWORD}@${MONGODB_HOST}:${MONGODB_PORT}/${MONGODB_AUTH_SOURCE}
```

I am running application from Dockerfile (with command: 'docker run --name test_app --network=root_mongodb_network -dp 8001:8001 test_app') which is on ubuntu server. There we have also another docker from docker-compose, fragment of file:

```
mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest # use the latest image
    container_name: mongodb
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - mongodb_network
    ports:
      - 27018:27017
    volumes:
      - /root/containers/mongodata:/data/db
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=user
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=userPass
    command: mongod --auth

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express:latest
    container_name: mongo-express
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    networks:
      - mongodb_network
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=user
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=userPass
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL=mongodb://root:userPass@mongo:27018/?authSource=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
      - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME=pass
      - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD=userPass
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
```

And i am not able to connect. Furthermore, I don't even have any log from mongodb docker that something is wrong when trying to connect. Worth noting - I am able to connect to the database from a local machine using the IP address of the server. Are you able to give me any hints as to what I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the error message of your script when trying to connect?

Comment: You are using `mongodb_network`  with the `mongodb` and `mongoexpress`.  While you running the application you mentioned network as `root_mongodb_network`. Is this something expected?

Comment: Got exception ServerSelectionTimeoutError, but no general error.
As i see in Portainer, they are assigned to network: root_mongodb_network, therefore i have also used that one. Kafka is working within the same network and with these credentials i am able to connect to Kafka.

Comment: Connections between containers don't require or use `ports:`.  Does setting `MONGODB_PORT=27017` to use the standard MongoDB port work better?